# PHP - String manipulation remove spcial characters and replace spaces

Tags: php, string

I am getting strings from a database and then using the strings to build a URL.  My issue is, some of the strings will have characters like < > & { } * general special characters, but the string may also have strings in. How would I replace the spaces with dashes and totally remove and special characters from the strings?

Comment: It might be easier to use urlencode(). It makes a string safe to use in URLs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
$str = str_replace(array(' ', '<', '>', '&', '{', '}', '*'), array('-'), $str);
```

Note:

> If *replace* has fewer values than *search*, then an empty string is used for the rest of replacement values.

Answer (score 9):

Keep only alphabets and numbers in a string using [`preg_replace`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

```
$string = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9-]/', '', $string);
```

You can use [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to replace space with -

```
$string = str_replace (" ", "-", $string);
```

Look at the following article:

- [How To Clean Special Characters From PHP String](http://www.bala-krishna.com/how-to-clean-special-characters-from-php-string/)

Comment: Iff you assume that there are no alphabetical characters outside A-Z, this would work; depending on your circumstances, this may or may not be too naïve an assumption.

Answer (score 2):

1) Replace diacritics with iconv
2) Replace non letter characters with empty string
3) Replace spaces with dash
4) Trim the string for the dash characters (you can also trim the string before manipulations)

Example, if you use UTF-8 encoding :

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'fr_CA.utf8');
$str = "%#dŝdèàâ.,d s#$4.sèdf;21df";

$str = iconv("UTF-8", "ASCII//TRANSLIT", $str); // "%#dsdeaa.,d s#$4.sedf;21df"
$str = preg_replace("`[^\w]+`", "", $str); // "dsdeaad s4sedf21df"
$str = str_replace(" ", "-", $str); // "dsdeaad-s4sedf21df"
$str = trim($str, '-'); // "dsdeaad-s4sedf21df"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$search_value =array(",",".",'"',"'","\\"," ","/","&","[","]","(",")"," 
{","}",":","`","!","@","#","%","=","+");
$replace_value =array("-","-","-","-","-","-","-","-","-","-","-","-","-","-","-","- 
","-","-","-","-","-");
$product_name = str_replace($search_value,$replace_value,$row["Product_Name"]);
$product_name = str_replace("--","-",$product_name);
$product_name = str_replace("--","-",$product_name);
$product_name = preg_replace('/-$/', '', $product_name);
$product_name = preg_replace('/^-/', '', $product_name);
```

This will create dashed string (Only have alphanumeric character with dash).Useful for create URI strings.

Answer (score 1):

```
str_replace(' ','-',$string);
```

alphanumeric:

```
$output = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/","",$input);
```

if you want to keep the characters:

```
 htmlspecialchars($string);
```