# How to strip everything from a variable apart from text and numbers

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP and i'm wondering how i would write a function like this, is there a existing function for this?

Comment: Define text! Is this `<i>text</i>`? Are you looking to strip HTML tags?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005282/php-string-manipulation-remove-spcial-characters-and-replace-spaces/4005292#4005292 for the simplest example, but note that there are (many) alphabetic characters outside of A-Z (even in English), and thus the example is rather naïve.

Answer (score 3):

You should really provide more context but `preg_replace('/[^[:alnum:]]/', '', $variable)` should work...